# How to match labels and instructions in an asm file using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, assembly

I am trying to extract labels and the instructions contained within from an asm file in python using regular expressions.

The asm code,

```
.data
    numOne: .word 10

    numTwo: 
        .word 20
.text
.globl main
main:
    lw $s1  , 0($s0)
    lw $s2, 4($s0)
    add $s3, $s1, $s2
    lw $s2,numOne
    jr $ra
foo:
    add $s3, $s1, $s2
    jr $ra
```

The labels in this case are,
'main' and 'foo', followed by instructions within each of them

Here is the pattern for a label that I have defined,

```py
label_pattern = re.compile(
    r"(\w+:)(\s*\w{2,3}\s*(\$[a-z0-9]{2}\s*,?\s*){1,3}(\d+\(\$[a-z][0-9]\))*)+\n?")
```

I am not able to match `lw $s2,numOne` (line 12) in the asm file using this pattern. The output is as follows,

```
main:
    lw $s1  , 0($s0)
    lw $s2, 4($s0)
    add $s3, $s1, $s2
    lw $s2,
foo:
    add $s3, $s1, $s2
    jr $ra
```

I have tried modifying the regex to match the word,

```
label_pattern = re.compile(
    r"(\w+:)(\s*\w{2,3}\s*(\$[a-z0-9]{2}\s*,?\s*){1,3}(\d+\(\$[a-z][0-9]\))*\w*)+\n?")
```

but I am not getting my desired result.

```
main:
    lw $s1  , 0($s0)
    lw $s2, 4($s0)
    add $s3, $s1, $s2
    lw
foo:
    add $s3, $s1, $s2
    jr
```

Please correct me. Thank you.

Edit: To clarify, I am trying to get the store the instructions in a dictionary with the label as a key and the list of instructions as values.

Here is the code that I have been using to check the output

```py
import re

label_pattern = re.compile(
    r"(\w+:)(\s*\w{2,3}\s*(\$[a-z0-9]{2}\s*,?\s*){1,3}(\d+\(\$[a-z][0-9]\))*\w*)+\n?")

test_pattern = re.compile(
    r"\s*\w{2}\s*\$[a-z][0-9]\s*,\s*(\d+\(\$[a-z][0-9]\))*\w+\s*"
) # this pattern matches the instruction lw $s2, numOne

f = open("instructionTest.asm", "r") # instructionTest.asm refers to the above asm code
matches = label_pattern.finditer(f.read())

for match in matches:
    if match:
        print(match.group())
```

I am expecting the following output, which contains the label and the instructions contained within.

```
main:
    lw $s1  , 0($s0) 
    lw $s2, 4($s0)   
    add $s3, $s1, $s2
    lw $s2,numOne
    jr $ra
foo:
    add $s3, $s1, $s2
    jr $ra
```

Edit 2: Request to reopen this question to get a possibly better solution

Comment: Which code does produce the output of which you say _is as follows_?

Comment: Are you trying to verify the format/specification for the portion you are trying to match or you are trying to extract the portion ?(if it is the latter there are lot more simpler ways to do it!)

Comment: How can you describe the "label" in terms of characters and their context? Regex can only match specific sequences of chars in specific contexts. The fact that it is an Assembler file does not throw any light upon the regex pattern requirements, what are they? Besides, what is your expected output?

Comment: It looks like your regex will only match a label that's on the *same* line as an instruction, because you used `+` instead of `*` for the possible-instruction part.  Try it on something like `foo: add $t0, $t1, $t2`.  But note that instructions like `b foo` involve an operand that's not a register so doesn't start with a `$`.  That's probably what's breaking in the `lw $s2,numOne` pseudo-instruction for `lw $s2, numOne($zero)`.

Comment: Also note that most assemblers don't allow labels to start with a digit, but *do* allow them to start with a `.`.  Or maybe not for MIPS syntax.  Normally GCC output is full of labels like `.L3:`, but MIPS GCC uses names like `$L3`.  https://godbolt.org/z/e48dYY.  IIRC, `\w` doesn't match `.` or `$`.  Traditional MIPS assembly (like MARS/SPIM use) may be different but probably does allow `$`.

Comment: @the23Effect I want to extract the portion. Could you please let me know what other ways are there to do this?

Comment: @Armali I have added the code that I have used to check the output. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hi, I have updated the post with my expected output. I want to extract the portions of the file with the following pattern,
[label]:[optional spaces or tabs or newlines][instructions on each line until the next label]
I want to get the label along with the instructions in it. Please look at the expected output that I have added. Thank you.

Comment: Can you reopen I have a much better and generic regex solution to this. I was busy so I didn't see your reply. Below is the regex: 
(?<=\n)(\w*:\n)([^\S\r\n]+?.*\n*)*
It's hard to explain this in comments.

Comment: This uses a zero length positive look behind first.

Comment: This even considers of contents of main: and foo: as separate matches.

Comment: The label and instructions are as separate groups in each match.

Comment: There is also verbose regex which is more readable. I can type an answer to teach you how to use that for your case.

Comment: @the23Effect Thank you, I would like to explore verbose regex. I have added clarifications in the question and requested for a reopen.

Comment: @the23Effect: It's reopened now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't get the expected output because the `\s` matches besides space and `\t` also `\n` and other whitespace characters, so `(\$[a-z0-9]{2}\s*,?\s*)` consumes the newline character after the input `add $s3, $s1, $s2` and the following `\w*` in `label_pattern` matches the `lw` instruction on the next line, disturbing further matching.
We get the expected output if we substitute those `\s` sequences with `[ \t]`:

```
r"(\w+:)(\s*\w{2,3}\s*(\$[a-z0-9]{2}[ \t]*,?[ \t]*){1,3}(\d+\(\$[a-z][0-9]\))*\w*)+\n?")
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought for a while and this is the best regex I could come up with:

```
(\n\w+:)((\n\s+.+)+)
```

You can tweak this a bit for even better results....

For extraction in python you can use the following code:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile("(\n\w+:)((\n\s+.+)+)")

f = open("instructionTest.asm", "r")
matches = pattern.finditer(f.read())

for match in matches:
    full_match = match.group(0)
    label = match.group(1)
    instructions = match.group(2)
```

Note: The above code will only get you the blocks of interest into their corresponding variables. You will still have to refine it by stripping away leading and trailing spaces.

**Using Really Long Regexes:**
For making long regexes readable, try using either re.VERBOSE in python or split the regex into multi lines.

VERBOSE:
Apart from splitting you can add comments like this within the regex string.  To read more about it check documentation [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) or [Blog Post](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/verbose-in-python-regex/)

```
pattern = re.compile(
    """
    (\n\w+:)                # This group gets you the label.
    ((\n\s+.+)+)            # This gets you the instructions.
    """, re.VERBOSE)
```

SPLITING REGEX:
Splitting them like this will maintain the readability and the regex structure.

```
pattern = re.compile(
    r"(\n\w+:)"                # This group gets you the label.
    r"((\n\s+.+)+)"            # This gets you the instructions.
)
```

Comment: If I'm reading this right, you're finding a label (in the leftmost column), and then taking all lines after it which have whitespace in the first column, and at least 1 more character.  In most modern assemblers, it's legal for a label to start in a column other than the 1st (the trailing `:` makes it unambiguous), and it's legal for instruction mnemonics to appear in the left-most column.  (Not all assemblers, though.  e.g. ARMasm assumes that a token in the left column is a label).  Also, you'll get empty lines that contain a couple spaces, and comment lines if the comments are indented.

Comment: It's also legal for a label to appear on the same line as an instruction, like `looptop: addiu $t0, $t0, -1`.  However, this might be a good answer for code that follows the indenting conventions / coding-style shown in the question.

Comment: True, am looking at the syntaxes to think of a better one now.

Comment: Then do numOne: and numTwo: qualify as labels ?

Comment: I believe numOne and numTwo are labels in the sense that they are address points but in my context, I am not trying to get extract them, because they are in the data segment. This solution is indeed elegant, however it assumes that a proper indentation is followed which need not be the case in a general assembly file as Peter pointed it out.

Comment: Yes, exactly, they're labels and they define symbols.  Good point, that proves that whatever assembler this asm is for does accept labels that don't start at the start of a line. If @KranthiS doesn't want to see the contents of the .data section, they'll have to keep track of section changes while parsing, and only capture lines that are after `.section .text` or its shortcut, `.text`.  (Or in the general case if this is GNU Assembler https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/, after a `.popsection` changes the current section back to .text after a `.pushsection .bss` or whatever.)

Comment: (Or they'll have to rely on indentation conventions if that's sufficient for their use-case.)